# Making an IP list using nmap and python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make an IP list using nmap and python so I used nmap to create a random IP list so the problem is that the list contains the text "Nmap scan report for" in ever line so I want a clean list without any text just IP
If there's is anyway please help me

Answer (score 0):

I used a text editor I used the replace function